# C++ Multiple variadic template not binded to function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic

I was trying to use some variadic template parameters but I was quickly stopped by an error I didn't managed to understand.

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  typedef T type;
};

// return a tuple of pair of args and Foo templated on Types
template <typename Head, typename ...Args, typename Type, typename ...Types>
auto func(Head arg, Args... args)
{
  return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(std::make_pair(arg, Foo<Type>())),
                       func<Args..., Types...>(args...));
}

template <typename Head, typename Type>
auto func(Head arg)
{
  return std::make_tuple(std::make_pair(arg, Foo<Type>()));
}

int main()
{
  func<int, bool, char>(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Here func try to unpack template parameters and make a tuple of pair of a func argument and a Foo struct templated on the second variadic template but I am having:

```
test.cc:25:3: error: no matching function for call to 'func'
 func<int, bool, char>(1, 2, 3);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:11:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Type'
 auto func(Head arg, Args... args)
 ^
test.cc:18:6: note: candidate function template not viable: requires single argument 'arg', but 3
  arguments were provided
 auto func(Head arg)
 ^
 1 error generated.
```

Why Type cannot be inferred ? (gcc told me the same)

I am sure that multiple variadic template is possible after seing std::tuple_cat implementation (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a01066_source.html) and I think this is a simple example and someone should knows better that me if there is a solution or if the standard doesn't accept this.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: What should it be deduced as? You told it `Head` and 2 `Args` ones and gave their respective function arguments. `Type` isn't used anywhere in there, so it can't possibly be deduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put deduced arguments last.

`...` template arguments are greedy -- they will consume passed in arguments and wont "save" any for later template arguments.

Once that is done, deduction occurs from non-template function arguments.

Swap like this:

```
template <typename Type, typename ...Types, typename Head, typename ...Args>
auto func(Head arg, Args... args)
```

Also, get rid of the other overload, so `func<int,int>(3)` is not ambiguous.

This makes the recursion break, but that is easy to fix:

```
template <class... Types, class... Args>
auto func(Args... args)
{
  return std::make_tuple(std::make_pair(args, Foo<Types>())...);
}
```

Which has the bonus of being nice and short.

Comment: Actually I need to template Foo only on 1 type so the second version does not work.
And the first one is still ambigous. It seems it doesn't want to unpack ...Args

Comment: @yayg I only pass `Foo` one type (at a time) in my second example...  Pack expansion works on expressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't knew about this awesome feature :D

Answer (score 0):

A key data point here is that a variadic parameter will be matched by an empty list. This has several consequences.

The first consequence is that given the following template declaration:

```
template <typename Head, typename ...Args, typename Type, typename ...Types>
```

and the following instantiation:

```
<int, bool, char>
```

There are several ways the instantiation can match the template:

1.

```
Head           int
...Args        bool
Type           char
... Types      (empty list)
```

2.

```
Head           int
...Args        (empty list)
Type           bool
... Types      char
```

So, that's one source of ambiguity. The reference in `main()` can match either template definition.  Although there are various arcane rules that in some instances can resolve this kind of ambiguity, it's always better not to rely on arcane template disambiguation rules, or at least go no further than use several standard, basic `SFINAE` approaches.

But, back on topic, right off the bat the compiler is going to be behind an eight-ball here, not having a clear candidate to resolve the template reference in `main()`. But it gets worse. Given

```
auto func(Head arg, Args... args)
```

and

```
auto func(Head arg)
```

Because, once again, a variatic parameter, in this case it's `Args...`, can match an empty list, then, for example:

```
func(4)
```

Can match either function signature.

Combine all of these factors together, and the compiler can't really make heads or tails here.